# ElasticSearch aggregate on a scripted nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-nested, elasticsearch-scripting

I have the following mapping in my ElasticSearch index (simplified as the other fields are irrelevant:

```json
{
  "test": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "entities": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "text_property": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "float_property": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The data looks like this (again simplified):

```json
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "entities": [
      {
        "text_property": "foo",
        "float_property": 0.2
      },
      {
        "text_property": "bar",
        "float_property": 0.4
      },
      {
        "text_property": "baz",
        "float_property": 0.6
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "entities": [
      {
        "text_property": "foo",
        "float_property": 0.9
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "entities": [
      {
        "text_property": "foo",
        "float_property": 0.2
      },
      {
        "text_property": "bar",
        "float_property": 0.9
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying perform a bucket aggregation on the maximum value of `float_property` for each document. So for the example above, the following would be the desired response:

```json
...
{
  "buckets": [
    {
      "key": "0.9",
      "doc_count": 2
    },
    {
      "key": "0.6",
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

as doc `a`'s highest nested value for `float_property` is 0.6, `b`'s is 0.9 and `c`'s is 0.9.

I've tried using a mixture of `nested` and `aggs`, along with `runtime_mappings`, but I'm not sure in which order to use these, or if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure this out in the end.

The two things I hadn't realised were:

1. You can provide a `script` instead of a `field` key to bucket aggregations.
2. Instead of using `nested` queries, you can access nested values directly using `params._source`.

The combination of these two things allowed me to write the correct query:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "max.float_property": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "double max = 0; for (item in params._source.entities) { if (item.float_property > max) { max = item.float_property; }} return max;"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```json
{
  ...
  "aggregations": {
    "max.float_property": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "0.9",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "0.6",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm confused though, because I thought the correct way to access `nested` fields was by using the `nested` query type. Unfortunately there's very little documentation for this, so I'm still unsure if this is the intended/correct way to aggregate on scripted nested fields.

Answer (score 0):

I created the index with your mappings changing float_property type to double.

```
PUT testindex
{
 "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "entities": {
          "type": "nested",
          "include_in_parent": true, 
          "properties": {
            "text_property": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "float_property": {
              "type": "double"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

> Added "include_in_parent":true for "nested" type

Indexed the documents:

```
PUT testindex/_doc/1
{
    "name": "a",
    "entities": [
      {
        "text_property": "foo",
        "float_property": 0.2
      },
      {
        "text_property": "bar",
        "float_property": 0.4
      },
      {
        "text_property": "baz",
        "float_property": 0.6
      }
    ]
  }
 
PUT testindex/_doc/2
{
    "name": "b",
    "entities": [
      {
        "text_property": "foo",
        "float_property": 0.9
      }
    ]
  }
  
PUT testindex/_doc/3 
{
    "name": "c",
    "entities": [
      {
        "text_property": "foo",
        "float_property": 0.2
      },
      {
        "text_property": "bar",
        "float_property": 0.9
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then Terms Aggregation on nested field:

```
POST testindex/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "entities.float_property": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "entities.float_property"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It produce the aggregation result as below:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "entities.float_property" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 0.2,
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : 0.9,
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        {
          "key" : 0.4,
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        {
          "key" : 0.6,
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: The issue is that I need to aggregate on the **max** value of the `float_property` - so in your example, there should not be a bucket with a key of 0.2 as the highest entity for document 'a' has a float property of 0.6, which is greater than 0.2.